# EntityFramework core group by gives me an order by

Tags: entity-framework-core

Here is my linq to sql query:

```
var data = 
    from p in dbcontext.person
    group p by p.city.ToLower() into g
    select new StatsViewModel { city = g.Key, citizen_count = g.Count() };
```

And here is the real sql query i get in sql server:

```
SELECT [p0].[id_person], [p0]....
      FROM [person] AS [p0]
      ORDER BY LOWER([p0].[city])
```

This is an order by, not a group by...

Comment: Bob, may be .Net core is not able to translate the whole linq expression to SQL and just ask for sorted data and make the projection and aggregation on app tier. May be?

Comment: This is a shame ! This would give wrong data. I prefer see a "non implemented" exception!

Comment: Just tested, [.Net Core EF Core 2.0.1 figure up the `group by` clause locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083443/842935) They are not exception, just a warning if you enable logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using debug (`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`) I can confirm your .Net Core EF 2.0.1 group by linq is not translate to SQL. A warning is raised:

> The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([p].City.ToLower(), [p])' could not
>   be translated and will be evaluated locally.

```
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10104]
      => Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor
      Optimized query model: 
      'from IGrouping<string, Person> g in 
          (from Person p in DbSet<Person>
          select [p]).GroupBy([p].City.ToLower(), [p])
      select new <>f__AnonymousType0<string, int>(
          [g].Key, 

              (from Person <generated>_1 in [g]
              select [<generated>_1]).Count()
      )'
```

A warning is raised:

```
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      => Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor
      The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([p].City.ToLower(), [p])' could not
      be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

Results are composed locally:

```
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10107]
      => Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor
      (QueryContext queryContext) => IEnumerable<<>f__AnonymousType0<string, int>> _InterceptExceptions(
          source: IEnumerable<<>f__AnonymousType0<string, int>> _Select(
              source: IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Person>> _GroupBy(
                  source: IEnumerable<Person> _ShapedQuery(
                      queryContext: queryContext, 
                      shaperCommandContext: SelectExpression: 
                          SELECT "p0"."ID", "p0"."City", "p0"."Name"
                          FROM "People" AS "p0"
                          ORDER BY lower("p0"."City"), 
                      shaper: UnbufferedEntityShaper<Person>), 
                  keySelector: (Person p) => string p.City.ToLower(), 
                  elementSelector: (Person p) => p), 
              selector: (IGrouping<string, Person> g) => new <>f__AnonymousType0<string, int>(
                  g.Key, 
                  int Count(g)
              )), 
          contextType: ConsoleApplication3.MyContext, 
          logger: DiagnosticsLogger<Query>, 
          queryContext: queryContext)
```

#### This is the code to reproduce it:

I post here the source code to help people who wants to know how to trace it:

**Model and dbcontext**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Person
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {

        public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
            = new LoggerFactory(new[] {new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)});

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=beer.db"); //Available here
            optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**Inserting data and making the Query**

```
        var ctx =new  MyContext();

        var p1=new Person();
        p1.City = "L'Escala";
        p1.Name = "Dani";
        ctx.People.Add(p1);

        var p2=new Person();
        p2.City = "L'Escala";
        p2.Name = "Dolors";
        ctx.People.Add(p2);

        var p3=new Person();
        p3.City = "Albons";
        p3.Name = "Joan";
        ctx.People.Add(p3);

        ctx.SaveChanges();

        var data1 = 
            from p in ctx.People
            group p by p.City.ToLower() into g
            select new { city = g.Key, citizen_count = g.Count() };

        data1.ToList();

        foreach (var v in data1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{v.city} - {v.citizen_count}");
        }
```

#### Results:

Results are ok:

```
albons - 1
l'escala - 2
```

#### Solution:

It looks [group by will be supported on next 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2341), evaluate if you can live with this performance issue this time.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue with the `GroupBy` translation of the current EF Core, tracked by the [Relational: Support translating GroupBy() to SQL #2341](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2341) and committed to be fixed in the next EF Core 2.1 release (according to the [EF Core Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap)). So until then, there is nothing you can do.

But don't be fooled by the generated SQL. EF Core uses a combination of so called [Cliend and Server Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval), which in this particular case means the `GroupBy` will be executed in memory after retrieving the result of the SQL query you see, so the actual result will be correct. The "only" problem could be the performance.

Comment: Hard to believe, although with all these EF Core bugs one never knows. What is wrong - the count? What if you remove `ToLower`?

Comment: The trace is identical after remove `ToLower`.

Comment: @danihp Well, trace does not show what exactly is happening. `ORDER BY` is concerning me, it shouldn't be needed if they do simply `Enumerable.GroupBy` (although the trace indicates that :/)

Comment: @IvanStoev, I guess it helps `Enumerable.GroupBy` because data comes sorted. Sure is like python itertools groupby that needs sorted data.

Comment: @Bob5421, they are not any bug. It works fine for me. I updated my answer with results.

Comment: @danihp That's what I meant. Any difference between database and C# equality comparison rules could break it.

Comment: @IvanStoev, yea, like collation. You are right. Ivan, I guess you are a kind of genius or you thing overmuch,